# Socket Receive equivalent on NetworkStream/TcpClient

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

Using socket I can do so to get the bytes

```
 Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
 s.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
 //
 FileStream fs = File.Create("1.jpg");
 fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 fs.Close();
```

I use this code to receive a byte [] of an image that I'm sending.

I need to convert this code to use TcpClient / NetworkStream to receive the byte [] sent
    enter code here

Answer (score 0):

This Code should be equivalent to yours:

```
var buffer = new byte[100000];
using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
    Client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
})
{
    await tcp.ConnectAsync("host", 12345);
    if (tcp.Connected)
    {
        using (var stream = tcp.GetStream())
        {
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

    }
}
using (var fs = File.Create("1.jpg"))
{
    await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```